# Go modules are not found using VGO and go.mod

Tags: go, vgo

I'm using versioned Go command to manage my vendors, everything is working but when I run `go build` it doesn't find my local packages

I have set the module root inside my `go.mod` with I still get an error

> build foo: cannot find module for path

The project arch is like

```
foo/
|__src/github.com/username/package1/package1.go
|__src/github.com/username/package2/package2.go
|__src/github.com/username/package3/package3.go
|__main.go
|__go.mod
|__go.sum
```

So my `go.mod` look like

```
module foo

require (
    ...
)
```

I followed https://research.swtch.com/vgo-tour but I don't understand why this is not working.

My Go version is `1.11` and the `foo` folder is inside my `GOPATH` when I try outside the `GOPATH` this is not even working.

The only time I made it work is doing

```
module github.com/username/package1

require (
    ...
)
```

but the 2 other packages are not found and I get the same error as above.

Did I miss something or do the module path I provide must be changed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your local packages imported are wrong, follow my example.

There is my `go.mod` (outside of `GOPATH`, I've imported `mux` for example):

```
module example

require github.com/gorilla/mux v1.6.2 // indirect
```

*BTW you can create an empty `go.mod`, `go` will find and update your `go.mod` for you.*

The `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    _ "example/src/foo" // local package
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/gorilla/mux" // example import
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

The `foo` local package:

```
package foo

import "fmt"

func bar() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

The module tree:

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── src
    └── foo
        └── foo.go
```

You can find more explanation here [`Modules`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#go-111-modules)